# How can I render a component in React to 2 different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS project. I have 3 components in the main page "Index component" as follows,

Nav-
Featured-
Footer

My Nav component has 2 links to 2 different components.
My Switch is as follows,

```
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" component={props => <Index {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="home" />
  </Switch>
```

I also have my Index component as follows,

```
   <React.Fragment>
       <Search />
       <Nav history={history} />
    {this.homePageComponents()}
       <Route
      path="/home/bedding"
      component={props => (
        <Bedding beddingProducts={this.beddingProducts()} {...props} />
      )}
    />
       <Route
      path="/home/bath"
      component={props => (
        <Bath bathProducts={this.bathProducts()} {...props} />
      )}
    />
       <Route path="/home/search" component={Search} />
  </React.Fragment>
```

I'm trying to render the Nav component to both Bath and Bedding products but whenever I import it and use it there it gives me an Error saying this.props.history.replace is undefined.
This is the project's link.
https://github.com/MaxOffline/beetle

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: It's saying this.props.history.replace is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your issue with using "withRouter" wrapper component which react-router provide to wrap your Nav component.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Thank you, That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log(this.props)` in the render method of nav.jsx you'll see that it contains a history object but that there is no replace method on that object.

You may be looking for the `this.props.history.push` method?

Comment: It was still undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple way to fix the problem.
All I needed to do is render components to the homepage conditionally so I simply added the following helper method to my "Index" Component.

```
homePageComponents = () => {
const featuredProducts = this.state.products.filter(
  product => product.featured === true
);
if (this.props.history.location.pathname === "/home") {
  return <Featured featuredProducts={featuredProducts} />;
}
```

};